# Add hyperlink to description with Azure DevOps Services REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My actual code which paste this as plain text, not as hyperlink:
POST to: https://dev.azure.com/{user}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.0-preview.3

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Link: https://stackoverflow.com/ "
  }
]
```

I want to achieve this effect, especially to have hyperlink in the description:

Description:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/

I can't put photo to the post so i put link to it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4cYR.png

Is it possible to add this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust your body to this:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "from": null,
    "value": "<div>Link: <a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/\">https://stackoverflow.com/</a></div>"
  }
]
```